# Implement train-test-validation split for a list of pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I want to implement a train-test-validation split for a list of dataframe.

For a single dataframe, I can do:

```
train, validate, test = np.split(df.sample(frac=1, random_state=42), [int(.6*len(df)), int(.8*len(df))])
```

However, I'm unable to implement it for a list of dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
train, validate, test = zip(*[(dfs[i][np.split(dfs[i].sample(frac=1, random_state), [int(.6*len(dfs[i])), int(.8*len(dfs[i]))]) for i in range(len(dfs))])])
```

Traceback:

```
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate directly over `dfs`

```
train, validate, test = zip(*[np.split(df, [int(.6*len(df)), int(.8*len(df))]) for df in dfs])
```

Or by index:

```
train, validate, test = zip(*[np.split(dfs[i], [int(.6*len(dfs[i])), int(.8*len(dfs[i]))]) for i in range(len(dfs))])
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `in range(len(dfs))` in the end?

Comment: @41726c. It depends on how you want to iterate over `dfs`: by item or by index. (Maybe you missed my update?)

Comment: you're right! :) think my comment and your update happened at the same time

Answer (score 1):

I would design the structure a bit differently by storing the sets into separate lists since your zip method tries to unpack your dataframes into separate variables.

Maybe the following code helps you out for your problem:

```
trainData = []
validateData = []
testData = []

for df in dfs:
    splitData = np.split(df.sample(frac=1, random_state=42), [int(.6*len(df)), int(.8*len(df))])
    trainData.append(splitData[0])
    validateData.append(splitData[1])
    testData.append(splitData[2])
```

And afterwards you can work with them by the corresponding indexing.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Define the size of the train, test, and validation sets
train_size = 0.7  # 70% of the data for training
test_size = 0.15  # 15% of the data for testing
val_size = 0.15   # 15% of the data for validation

# Split the list of dataframes into train and test sets
train_data, test_data = train_test_split(dataframes, test_size=test_size, random_state=42)

# Split the test set further into test and validation sets
test_data, val_data = train_test_split(test_data, test_size=val_size/(test_size+val_size), random_state=42)
```